# How can we destroy child objects in edit mode(Unity3d)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It is kind of strange things, but if you'll try to destroy child objects with `DestroyImmediate` function, then you will have unpredictabe result.

In my case Unity did not destroyed all childs, but did it for only half of them.

```
        foreach(var child in parent)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(child);
        }
```

Comment: From Unity's document on `DestroyImmediate`: _Also note that you should never iterate through arrays and destroy the elements you are iterating over. This will cause serious problems (as a general programming practice, not just in Unity)._ https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As one guy consider in link it is possible with creating temp array/list.

For example:

```
        var tempArray = new GameObject[parent.transform.childCount];

        for(int i = 0; i < tempArray.Length; i++)
        {
            tempArray[i] = parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        }

        foreach(var child in tempArray)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(child);
        }
```

Link that helped me:
http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/678073/view.html

Answer (score 23):

This is how i destroy children in Edit Mode:

```
for (int i = this.transform.childCount; i > 0; --i)
    DestroyImmediate(this.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
```

Comment: Note for others: Emphasis here on iterating in decrements and using `GetChild(0)` instead of `GetChild(i)`